# Components aren't re-rendered after setState update, requires updating twice before re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, filtering, hubspot

I am creating a custom blog listing page in React for a HubSpot site (I've already searched there, couldn't find anything relevant to my issue). I'm still somewhat new to React but it is my first project from scratch in over a year. Basically what I am trying to do is combine three separate blogs into one page and add filtering options to show only posts from certain blogs and/or posts with certain tags attached to them. Currently I am successfully pulling the post data and sorting it. I am almost finished with the filtering functionality, but I am hitting a snag when trying to reset all filters.

I understand that setState is asynchronous and you can't expect the state value to updated immediately. My issue is that even after I have successfully updated the state, the useEffect hook doesn't fire consistently. I have tabs at the top of the page to switch between blogs and that works perfectly, as soon as I click one it filters out every other blog post and I can go back and forth between them easily. The problem is on the reset, I have to click the button twice for it to work. I'm completely at a loss as to why this is. In the console I see that the useEffect function for blogActive fires after the first time I click the reset button, but the blog view doesn't change. The second time I click the reset button, the blog view changes but the useEffect function doesn't fire.

I know that useEffect isn't supposed to fire if the state isn't actually updated (its being set to undefined when the button is clicked, so the second time it won't change) but I am still confused as to why this happens with the reset button and not with the blog switch function. I was originally resetting the blog from the reset function instead of just the sort function but that wasn't working either and calling it from the sort function is simpler in terms of displaying results with resetting the other filters (I have removed the tag filtering functions and components and still get the same results). I've also tried calling the handleBlogSwitch method instead of using the setState hook but I get the same results.

I've pasted the most relevant code below, but I've also included a sandbox link with a skeleton of the whole project including the code to fetch the post data.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
function Blog({ blogName, blogID, handleBlog }) {
  return (
    <div className="blog">
      <button className={"blog-" + blogName} onClick={() => handleBlog(blogID)}>
        {blogName}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Blog;

function Archive() {

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [blogActive, setBlog] = useState();
  const [resetCheck, setChecked] = useState([]);
  const [postState, setPosts] = useState(postArray);

  let postArray = [];

  function handleBlogSwitch(id) {
    setBlog(id);
  }

  function sortPosts(sortme) {
    let resetSort = false;
    if (sortme) {
      sortme.sort((a, b) => b["dataset"]["date"] - a["dataset"]["date"]);
      postArray = [...postArray, ...sortme];
    } else if (sortme === false) {
      resetSort = true;
      setBlog(() => {
        return undefined;
      });
    }
    let filtered = postArray;
    if(!resetSort) {
      if (blogActive) {
        filtered = blogFilter(filtered);
        setLoader("spinner-loaded");
      }
    }
    setPosts(filtered);
    setLoader("spinner-loaded");
  }

  function resetFilters(resetThis) {
    setChecked([]); // Uncheck everything
    sortPosts(resetThis);
  }

// Handle logic for blog and tag filters
  useEffect(() => {
    setBtnLoad("btn-load-more"); // add this to the useEffect hook for tags too.
    if(blogActive) {// Don't run this on page load. 
      sortPosts();
      console.log("test blogactive effect");
    }
  }, [blogActive]);

 return (
    <div className="results__container">
      <div className="tabs__container">
        {Blogs.blogs.map((blog, key) => (
          <Blog
            key={key}
            blogName={blog.name}
            blogID={blog.id}
            handleBlog={handleBlogSwitch}
          ></Blog>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="filter__container">
            <button onClick={() => resetFilters(false)}>Reset Filters</button>
        <div className="posts__container">
          {postState.slice(0, page * resultsPerPage).map((html, key) => (
            <Posts key={key} postHtml={html.outerHTML}></Posts>
          ))}
          <img className={loader} src={logoSrc} />
          <button className={btnClass} onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>
            Load More
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Archive;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-lalande-0w16yu?file=/src/App.js

Update: I didn't really fix this bug I'm facing, but I found a workaround. Instead of relying on the value of blogActive in sortPosts(), I created a new boolean in sortPosts which is set to true when it is called from the reset function. This way I know that the states should be resetting and skip that code, even if they aren't caught up yet.

Comment: there are many states and many useEffects for a simple filtered infinite scroll, you might want to consider using react-query

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon I would like to avoid adding new dependencies and rework how this whole thing is operating, especially if I can solve it with standard react. I'm also not sure that you can install other repos when using hubspot's react boilerplate, so it could be futile anyway.